# How to make grunt-newer run requirejs on only changed files?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I can only find [examples](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/737/files) about using `grunt-newer` with `jshint` but not `requirejs` during searching. So I use this config in my grunt config file:

```
watch: {
    options: {
        nospawn: true
    },
    js: {
        files: [
            'public/**/*.js',
            '!public/asset/**/*.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['newer:requirejs']
    },
},
requirejs: getRequirejsOptions(),
...
```

the requirejs options is like this:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var options = {};

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        options[file] = {
            options: {
                baseUrl: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
                include: file,
                create: true,
                out: path.join(__dirname, '../public/asset/', file + '.js'),
                optimize: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'local' ? 'none' : 'uglify',
                preserveLicenseComments: !false,
                packages: [
                  ...
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    return options;
}
```

it did fire the `grunt watch` to run `requirejs` on only changed files:

```
$ grunt watch                                                       
Running "watch" task Waiting...
>> File "public/stock/js/main.js" changed.

Running "newer:shell:requirejs" (newer) task No newer files to process.

Running "watch" task Completed in 1.834s at Fri Jan 06 2017 12:08:05 GMT+0800 (CST) - Waiting...
```

but after refreshing browser, I found the source file not changed.

Comment: What files is `requirejs` using as its source? I suspect removing the `newer` from the task run by `watch:js` would fix this.

Comment: If remove newer, `grunt watch` will compile all js files even only one file changed. I want `grunt watch` to compile only the changed files.

Comment: Nevertheless, you need to include the `requirejs` task configuration for the question to be answerable. `watch:js` is seeing a change that is not seen by `newer:requirejs` - so the latter's source files are significant.

Comment: ok, I've updated the question.

Comment: My understanding of `newer` was that it worked with tasks that had `src` (and `dest`) files in their configuration and I've only used it with such tasks. I don't know how it would work with a task like your `requirejs` task. (Also, I'm not sure why `requirejs` is in your `watch` config or whether that's a typo. I'd have thought that `requirejs` would have had to have been a top-level key in the Grunt configuration.)

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Sorry for that.